# In Gradle, failing to modify xml after copying into project

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy, build, gradle

I have some common xml files that are included into the jars of my builds that need to be modified after copying from a shared location.  The code fails with a No such file or directory error because the file doesn't exist until after it is copied over.  How can I get around this?  The file is modified often, so copying into each project and maintaining is not really an option.  Is there a way to assure gradle that the file will be there soon?

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

apply plugin: 'java'

task copyCR(type: Copy) {
    from '../../copyrights/cr.xml' //XML file shared across many projects
    into 'copyrights'
}
task specializeCR(dependsOn: copyCR) {
    def root = new XmlSlurper().parse('./copyrights/cr.xml')
    root.copyright.@Name = 'Project Specific XML settings'
    def outputBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
    new FileWriter('./copyrights/cr.xml') << outputBuilder.bind{ mkp.yield root }
}
build {
    dependsOn specializeCR
}
clean{
    delete 'copyrights'
}
sourceSets{
    main{
        resources{
            srcDir 'copyrights'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe not a solution, but eliminating a step: couldn't you just parse from `../../copyrights/cr.xml` in the specializeCR step?

Comment: A tip: use project.file(path) or similar method http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:file(java.lang.Object) to make sure that path is resolved against well defined location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All work performed by a task need to go into a *task action*:

```
task specializeCR(dependsOn: copyCR) {
    doLast { // add a task action for this task 
        ...
    }
}
```

`specializeCR` needs to be depended on by the task(s) that use the file (not by `build`). Otherwise, there is no guarantee that it will be executed at the right time.